# VS Code Error persistence, how do I get VS Code to detect I've fixed The issues in referenced code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

While trying to do test driven development in vs code. I have the tester code in one window and the code I'm testing in another. The tester and program are different projects with the tester referencing the program.

I have to reopen the window I'm the writing test in to have vs code stop underlining errors I've fixed or show errors I've just introduced in the programs code (which the tester code is referencing).

I've tried to restore, build, and clean my test to have vs code detect the changes. I've also reset the settings in vs code to see if that was the problem. Only closing the window and reopening works.

Is there a simpler way to get vs code to detect that the issue is fixed?

P.S.
I'm writing in C# if that matters.

Also sorry if there are any issues with the way I've asked this question it's my first and if there's any feedback I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seem to have found a fix for the issue so I'm posting it here.

I've added the parent folder containing both projects to a workspace and now it updates when I fix or break something.

P.S.
This may not be the correct way to do this if it isn't let me know.